# tailwind div hover does not take effect on all its children

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Having this html:

```
<div className='flex flex-col hover:bg-red-500 hover:text-white'>
      <span className='font-semibold'>bold text</span>
      <span className='text-gray-500'>gray text</span>
</div>
```

only `bold text` gets white when hover over. The `gray text` stays gray. How to make `hover:text-white` be applied on both `spans`?

Comment: Coul you add your css code?

Comment: This looks like a specificity/cascade issue. The second span has its text color set (text-gray-500)  so it's not going to pick up the setting from the parent's hover:text-white;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group` modifier in Tailwind to style an element based on the parent's state.

Your first mark the parent by adding `group` class to it. Then you do your child state's in the children by using `group-hover:[style]`.

So your code should like this:

```
<div className="flex flex-col hover:bg-red-500 group">
    <span className="font-semibold group-hover:text-white">bold text</span>
    <span className="group-hover:text-white">gray text</span>
</div>
```

You can find more information [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state).